# MySQL in Python broken in virtualenv after move to 12.04

Tags: python, mysql

This morning I upgraded my Xubuntu to 12.04.

The virtualenv has moved up a version, and now bundles pip and I've had to rearrange some scripts to cope with this and rebuild my virtualenvs.

MySQL dbapi is now giving me strange errors.  It can only create InnoDB tables; if you try an create MyISAM tables (from Python code), it raises:

```
NotSupportedError: (1286, "Unknown storage engine 'MyIASM'")
```

When I run the mysql command-line program itself, its happy to create both InnoDB and MyISAM tables.

What is configured wrongly and how do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe just a typo :) MyISAM, not MyIASM

Comment: @EwanHeming indeed you were correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed a typo.

On some platforms and with some client libraries (I guess its a warning level setting), unrecognised engine types silently default to the default table type.

Ouch.